# Download sqlite database from remote server(SFTP) using php

Tags: php, sftp

I am currently working on a project where I need to download  sqlite database to local folder.So is it possible to download a SQLite database from a webserver, then search the database for content? I am very new to php and  i just got to this point and got stuck with this error.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function ssh2_connect()

```
<?php
$host = '11.11.11.2';
$port = 2222;
$username = 'root';
$password = 'sdfsdf';
$remoteDir = '/home/root/systools/WM/WebMobility.db';
$localDir = '/c:/explode';

if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect"))
    die('Function ssh2_connect not found, you cannot use ssh2 here');

if (!$connection = ssh2_connect($host, $port))
    die('Unable to connect');

if (!ssh2_auth_password($connection, $username, $password))
    die('Unable to authenticate.');

if (!$stream = ssh2_sftp($connection))
    die('Unable to create a stream.');

if (!$dir = opendir("ssh2.sftp://{$stream}{$remoteDir}"))
    die('Could not open the directory');

$files = array();
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir)))
{
    if ($file == "." || $file == "..")
        continue;
    $files[] = $file;
}

foreach ($files as $file)
{
    echo "Copying file: $file\n";
    if (!$remote = @fopen("ssh2.sftp://{$sftp}/{$remoteDir}{$file}", 'r'))
    {
        echo "Unable to open remote file: $file\n";
        continue;
    }

    if (!$local = @fopen($localDir . $file, 'w'))
    {
        echo "Unable to create local file: $file\n";
        continue;
    }

    $read = 0;
    $filesize = filesize("ssh2.sftp://{$sftp}/{$remoteDir}{$file}");
    while ($read < $filesize && ($buffer = fread($remote, $filesize - $read)))
    {
        $read += strlen($buffer);
        if (fwrite($local, $buffer) === FALSE)
        {
            echo "Unable to write to local file: $file\n";
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose($local);
    fclose($remote);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ssh_*` function are not per default installed in php core.
You have to add them using pecl, see php manual for a good description: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ssh2.installation.php

Comment: Hi Ali, can you tell me where this needs to be installed  i installed it on xampp/php/ext folder..

Comment: I installed it and i am getting hhtp.exe entry point not found error followed by unable to load dynamic library C;\xampp\php\ext\php_ssh2.dll . the specified procedure could not be found

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have an easier time using [phpseclib, a pure PHP SFTP implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/sftp/intro.html). Not only would it make for more portable and easily deployable code than libssh2 but it'd also make for shorter code too:

```
<?php
$host = '11.11.11.2';
$port = 2222;
$username = 'root';
$password = 'sdfsdf';
$remoteDir = '/home/root/systools/WM/WebMobility.db';
$localDir = '/c:/explode';

include('Net/SFTP.php');

$sftp = new Net_SFTP($host, $port);
if (!$sftp->login($username, $password))
    die('Unable to authenticate.');

$files = $sftp->nlist($remoteDir);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if ($file == "." || $file == "..")
        continue;

    $sftp->get($remoteDir . '/' . $file, $localDir . $file);
}
```

Comment: Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.6

Comment: Did you download phpseclib? Is it in your `include_path`? My guess is that if you changed include to require you'd be getting an error on that line instead because you don't have phpseclib installed correctly..